# Saving and opening tabs like in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to create tabs with jQuery and Ajax etc. I want to implement the tabs functionalities in Chrome and Firefox whereby the last opened tabs in a user's session are opened again when the user launches the browser.

All the tabs that were opened when the site is closed are opened again when the user opens the site again.

I am asking for ideas how I can do it. Am using PHP as a programming language. I want to create similar functionality in my site.

Comment: Not sure I get it, but is your goal to create similar tabs inside a website, or to control the actual browser tabs? If the latter, forget it, it's not yours to fiddle with.

Comment: I  want to create similar functionality in my site

Comment: So, fake tabs inside HTML/Javascript? What have you tried then, what problem is keeping you?

Comment: what do you mean fake tabs? I don't have any code yet neither am i asking for code. Am just asking for ideas how i can do it. That is all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Supports history management, persistent cookies, ajax population, and much more...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the cookie only persists which tab that was selected, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your simple answer. I appreciate it. Can you point me to the place where i can read more about the  "history management, persistent cookies"?  thanks

Comment: There's navigation on the right side of that page with its different features

Answer (score 0):

For history management I recommend to take a look at [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/)

For persistent cookies you also need the cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie